# KDE keyboard switcher not always appearing

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, kde, kde-plasma-5

The KDE keyboard switcher applet keeps randomly disappearing after I upgraded to Fedora 23. Yesterday I fixed this problem by rebooting, I think. But now rebooting does not help.

However, if I start a new session with a different user, and enable keyboard "switching" for one keyboard layout, the keyboard switcher applet appears for that user.

I looked in pstree but I couldn't find the process responsible for the keyboard switcher applet.

How can I make it reappear in the original user's account? We can use the keyboard shortcut as a workaround, but the user does not want to have to memorise workarounds like this.

Comment: I filed [a bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357384).

Comment: There is a superbug describing several problems with KDE5 layout switcher: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295438

Answer (score 0):

This works, but is not very satisfactory - I can't expect the user to memorise all this!

1. Right-click on an area of the system tray which is for some reason, empty. (Side note: I think this is part of the problem - not all applets are appearing, or appearing properly, in the system tray.)
2. Choose "System tray settings"
3. Choose the second settings panel, called "Entries"
4. Set the Keyboard Layout visibility dropdown to "Hidden"
5. Click the Apply button
6. Set the Keyboard Layout visibility dropdown to "Shown"
7. Click the OK button